# Box2d cpp gives : box2d expression area > 1.1 exception

Tags: c++, box2d

i have strange error :

```
#define PTM_RATIO 32
// shape
            b2PolygonShape axleShape;
            axleShape.SetAsBox(20/PTM_RATIO,20/PTM_RATIO);

            // fixture
            b2FixtureDef axleFixture;
            axleFixture.density=0.5;
            axleFixture.friction=3;
            axleFixture.restitution=0.3;
            axleFixture.shape=&axleShape;
            axleFixture.filter.groupIndex=-1;
            // body definition
            b2BodyDef axleBodyDef;
            axleBodyDef.type=b2_dynamicBody;
            // the rear axle itself
            axleBodyDef.position.Set(m_cart->GetWorldCenter().x-(60/PTM_RATIO),m_cart->GetWorldCenter().y+(65/PTM_RATIO));
            b2Body* rearAxle =m_world->CreateBody(&axleBodyDef);
            rearAxle->CreateFixture(&axleFixture);
            // the front axle itself
            axleBodyDef.position.Set(m_cart->GetWorldCenter().x+(75/PTM_RATIO),m_cart->GetWorldCenter().y+(65/PTM_RATIO));
            b2Body* frontAxle=m_world->CreateBody(&axleBodyDef);
            frontAxle->CreateFixture(&axleFixture);
```

in the last line im getting exception that says :
[image]

when i change it to :

```
axleShape.SetAsBox(40/PTM_RATIO,40/PTM_RATIO);
```

it is working , but its not in the right size i need .
how can i make small box's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case of integer division. When you pass `20/PTM_RATIO` into SetAsBox method, that is the same as `20/32`, which evaluates to `0`.

You can fix this by changing this first line to `#define PTM_RATIO 32.0`. The point zero at the end should make all of the division expressions evaluate to a decimal.

The assert "area > 1.192092896E-07" makes sure that the area of the shape is larger than that number. The program won't compile if the assert fails. At the moment, you're passing in a half-width and half-height of 0, which means that the area of the rectangle will be 0, and this causes the assert to fail.